# Send 404 header from not existent static content when using * route in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'v got express app like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);

app.get('*', function(res,req) {
    req.render('index', {title: "Title"});
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Because of using `app.get('*')` request to not existent static files responses with rendered `index.ejs` file instead of error 404.

Is there any way to fix it without additional conditions in routes?

Comment: How would Express know what's static and what isn't?

Comment: Unless you define what exactly is static content. Otherwise, get * will caught everything that can not be matched by the rule before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem by nginx proxying

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like:

```
app.get(/\/(js|css|img)\/.*/, function (req, res) {
  res.send(404);
});
```

before `app.get('*')`. Any request to `/js` that wasn't already matched by the static middleware references an file that does not exist.

Comment: It doesn`t work: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` this starts static file server and requests to files in it goes without `public/` (for example `/js/script.js`), so there is no ability to configure routes like this `public*`